# Map.put error - getting unexpected token error

Tags: trigger, error, map

This is the code I am using:

```
trigger ParentOppToChild on Opportunity (after update)
{

    List <Opportunity> oppQueryResults = new List <Opportunity>([Select ID, (Select ID, Dealership__c From OpportunityLineItems) From Opportunity]);

    Map<ID,OpportunityLineItem> accountTolineItems = New Map<ID,OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(Opportunity o : oppQueryResults)
    {
        if(o.StageName = 'Closed Won')
        {
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli : o.OpportunityLineItems)
            {

                accountToLineItems.put(oli.Dealership__c, new OpportunityLineItem{oli});

                if(accountToLineItems.containsKey(oli.Dealership__c))
                {
                    accountToLineItems.containsKey(oli.Dealership__c).add(oli);
                }
                else
                {
                    accountToLineItems.put(oli.Dealership__c,New OpportunityLineItem[]{oli});
                }
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

And this is the error that I am getting:
unexpected token: '{' at line 21

Sorry if this is really obvious but I have changed the code around so many times because of this and I can't seem to find an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Which line is line 21 ?

Comment: @BarCotter accountToLineItems.put(oli.Dealership__c, new OpportunityLineItem{oli});

Comment: If you want dealership to be the key and the `oli` variable to be the value then you should be doing the following: `accountToLineItems.put(oli.Dealership__c, oli);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your complete use case.. you shouldn't be querying all the opportunities and its line items in your trigger.. you should just limit the opportunity records that got updated.

but to the error, you should change

```
accountToLineItems.put(oli.Dealership__c, new OpportunityLineItem{oli});
```

to

```
accountToLineItems.put(oli.Dealership__c, new List<OpportunityLineItem>());
```

but you are doing this initialization inside the for loop which is not required since the next if.. else.. part takes care of the initialization as well..

and also you should change this line as well

```
accountToLineItems.containsKey(oli.Dealership__c).add(oli);
```

to

```
accountToLineItems.get(oli.Dealership__c).add(oli);
```

so, your overall code will look like this

```
trigger ParentOppToChild on Opportunity (after update)
{

    List <Opportunity> oppQueryResults = new List <Opportunity>([Select ID, (Select ID, Dealership__c From OpportunityLineItems) From Opportunity]);

    Map<ID,OpportunityLineItem> accountTolineItems = New Map<ID,OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(Opportunity o : oppQueryResults)
    {
        if(o.StageName = 'Closed Won')
        {
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli : o.OpportunityLineItems)
            {

                if(accountToLineItems.containsKey(oli.Dealership__c))
                {
                    accountToLineItems.get(oli.Dealership__c).add(oli);
                }
                else
                {
                    accountToLineItems.put(oli.Dealership__c, new List<OpportunityLineItem>());
                }
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: I need to get a related list of line items and each line items dealership(dealership__c) is this not the right way to do it?

Comment: I hv updated my answer.. thou this will get thru the compile error, I am not sure about your complete business logic & what exactly you are trying to achieve in this trigger.

Comment: Can you check my last question to see what it is I need to do? No one has provided any clarification on that. That will explain what I am trying to do. Thanks for your help on this but it says there is an error now on line 23: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [OpportunityLineItem].add(OpportunityLineItem)

Answer (score 0):

Instead use this on line 21 :

```
accountToLineItems.put(oli.Dealership__c,New list<OpportunityLineItem>{oli});
```

Also look this link : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000913SIAQ

Comment: This gives an error: Incompatible value type List<OpportunityLineItem> for Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>

Comment: Have you included {oli} or just list<OpportunityLineItem>() because accountToLineItems is map of ID and Opp Line Item object (not list of object). Please verify. :)

Comment: I just pasted that line of code you suggested in place of the line I had and I got that error. Now I feel like I might be approaching this the wrong way :/